# Installation Issue - Database Triggers not allowed by hosting provider

Tags: database, installation, mysql

After spending 3 months configuring and testing CiviCRM on a locally hosted/internal server (and being suitably impressed), I attempted to install onto our website which is hosted with GoDaddy.

I kept running into an error that prevented CiviCRM from installing being that I am unable to install triggers on the DB due to permissions in a shared server environment.

I appear to have 2 options:
1 - fork out more $$$ to get a dedicated server or VPS.  Not possible.

2 - Move from GoDaddy to HostGator who claim to allow triggers. "We can enable trigger privileges for your database, simply contact us via phone or Live Chat with the database, database user, and the tables that you require the permissions on."

Can anyone provide a list of tables that require the trigger permissions added please?

Or provide an alternate hosting solution/suggestion, noting that the organisation is a Not For Profit based in Nepal and not able to spend much money on a solution.

Thanks, Joe.

Answer (score 2):

The tables that use triggers are: `civicrm_contact`, `civicrm_address`, `civicrm_phone`, `civicrm_email`, `civicrm_im`, and `civicrm_phone`.  Additionally, if you turn on advanced logging, all tables have triggers.  The Summary Fields extension also creates triggers.

The "core" triggers are mainly used for updating the `modified_date`, though they also generate a value for a hidden numeric-only phone field (used for SMS etc.).

In all though - I would NOT use GoDaddy for hosting.  CiviCRM uses far more resources than a brochureware WordPress site.  While I hear your concerns about cost, there's plenty of VPS services that cost the same as GoDaddy hosting - assuming you or someone else is willing to manage the server.  I use Linode, whose $10/month plan will give you far better performance than any shared hosting out there.  There's equivalent plans from smaller VPS providers too.

Comment: Thanks Jon G.  I have been in touch with Linode and the packages do indeed seem reasonable.  Are you interested in assisting a poor volunteer working in Nepal to do server setup and migration of a very basic (static HTML) website? :)